# Run custom Dita-OT from Java application

Tags: java, dita

So I have a Java program that fetches some data from different places and writes DITA files. I also want to have the PDF file for which I have created a custom DITA-OT plugin. Normally I run Dita-OT after my program has executed but what if I wanted to run Dita-OT automatically too? How could that be achieved?

So I'd like to package my custom Dita-OT with my Java application so that the Java app could automatically generate the PDF file in the end. Has someone done something like this or has otherwise pointers?

I thought about packaging DITA-OT inside the resources folder of my Java project from which I would execute the DITA-OT but I guess that won't work when I package my application inside a jar.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate all these things with Ant or Gradle. You can download/install an Open Toolkit and start a transformation. Packing the Open Toolkit with your application would inflate the size of your application, so this is probably more elegant. Or you might take a closer look at the [dost.jar](http://www.dita-ot.org/1.8/readme/building-output-using-cl-tool.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply package DITA-OT inside a JAR because Ant in DITA-OT will not be able to read resources from the classloader. The easiest way is to simply install DITA-OT somewhere where your application has read access and then run DITA-OT's Ant process. You can either

- Fork a new JVM and run DITA-OT there
- Use the current JVM and run Ant's `Project` object with DITA-OT's `build.xml`.

The former will give you the security that DITA-OT will not bring your application down with a `OutOfMemoryError`, but the latter will be faster once the JVM warms up.